# How to make datepicker value dd/mm/yyy

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing an asp.net mvc application, in which I'm trying to get a Date value using a datepicker, I've been struggling a lot to find an appropriate solution but no success, what I want it to accept:
**dd/mm/yyyy**
but after picking the date, the datepicker take always this format: **mm/dd/yyyy**

Screenshot

[image]

The problem that the ModelState will be not valid the day's value is bigger als 12 (debugger read that as month).

View Code :

```
 <input id="datepicker" name="Date" type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'dd/mm/yyyy';}" required="">
<script>
    $(function ()
    {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
    });
</script>
```

Model code :

```
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Comment: Change your server culture to one that accepts date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format if that is what you expect the users to post the format in

Comment: Alternatively create a custom ModelBinder for dates

Comment: I tried that with adding globalization in web config but it didn't work, The ModelBinder I didn't try it coz I have no idea about but I will look if it work

Comment: Similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559112/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ui-datepicker-date-format & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209040/how-to-use-jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-4-with-custom-format-dd-mm-yyyy. You can set `globalization culture="[culture with dd/MM/yyyy format]"` too.

Comment: Then you did not try it correctly!

Comment: @StephenMuecke When you tell using model binder, you must be refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813345/wrong-dateformat-with-jquery-datepicker. I think OP can register custom model binder if he gives attempt to do it.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thanks for your answers, I will try it again despite I ve seen before and they didn't work for me, I want to ask if the creating of Modelbinder is necessary

Answer (score 2):

datepicker provide option to give date format.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

If required then try to change current culture from `Global.asax file`

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
  CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo) System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
  newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MMM/yyyy";
  newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
}
```

Comment: @Exact : first remove these event . onfocus and onblur from textbox then check.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your question, I am beginner, what do you mean by plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can customize dateFormat for jquery UI datepicker.

```js
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

Change your datepicker line to this.

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

Comment: yes I have Jquery, ok I will try again and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can add simple option `format` :

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0, format:"dd/mm/yyyy"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sample use

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' })
```

Instead if you want to read the value :

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks but as Amit said I want to change the format not get the value